# Javascript: Calculate balance and advance through text field input

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner to JavaScript. I have code through which the user enters the value through the input field ('to enter the given fees'). What I want is, if the user types more than '1000', then the advance value should come in the another input text('advance fee').

If the user types less than '1000', then the balance amount should come in another text input ('balance fees').

My [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Keynes105/3dyu5dqq/) carries the way I worked in.

My Html form is :

```
 <form>
<div class="tbl_admission_FormCell">Given Fees</div> 
  <div class="tbl_admission_FormCell" style="padding:10px;"><input type="text" name="given_fees" value="" id="given_fees" onkeypress="givenfees()" onkeyup="givenfees()"/> </div> 

<div class="tbl_admission_FormCell">Balance Fees</div> 

<div class="tbl_admission_FormCell"><span id="balance_fees"></span> </div>

 <div class="tbl_admission_FormCell">Advance Fees</div> 

 <div class="tbl_admission_FormCell"><span id="advance_fees"></span> </div>
 <div class="tbl_admission_FormRow"> 
  <div class="tbl_admission_FormCell">Total Fees</div>
    <div class="tbl_admission_FormCell"><input type="text" id="total_fees" name="total_fees" style="border:none;" value="1000" readonly/></div> 
  <div class="tbl_admission_FormCell"><div class="amt_total" onchange="amt_total()" ></div></div>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
function givenfees(){
    var given_fees = document.getElementById("given_fees");
    var s = given_fees.value;
    bal_value = +s - +result;       
    var balance_fees = document.getElementById("balance_fees");
    if(+bal_value<0 )
    {
    advance_fees.innerText = +bal_value;
    }
    else
    {balance_fees.innerText = +bal_value;}
}
</script>
```

Comment: `result` is not defined!

Comment: @rafter, i could not process the result, i am seeking for help..But i have mentioned my desired output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your answer. Please check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0horumyj/2/). Hope this will help you if I understand your problem exactly.

```
function givenfees(){ 
    var result=1000;
    var given_fees = document.getElementById("given_fees");
    var s = given_fees.value;
    bal_value = +s - +result;    
    var balance_fees = document.getElementById("balance_fees");
    if(+bal_value>0 )
    {
    advance_fees.innerText = +bal_value;
    balance_fees.innerText = 0;
    }
    else
    {
    balance_fees.innerText = +bal_value;
    advance_fees.innerText = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer & fiddle. i have missed to make the advance/balance as '0' after the actual balance. It has helped me..

Comment: please give a upvote and accept this question as am not satisfied with the negative vote..:)

Answer (score -1):

Keep calling 'calValue' function onchange of input1

```
function calValue(){
  var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
  if(input1 >= 1000){
    input2.value = input1 - 1000;
  }else{
    input2.value = 1000 - input1;
  }
}
```